# How to make web changes without debug mode in VS2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015

I used Visual Studio 2010 and 2012. In both versions, when I stopped debugging my website, the website would still work in the browser. This means as long as I didn't make any code behind changes (that I didn't need to rebuild) I could continue working on the HTML/JavaScript/CSS side.

It appears this option is not default in 2015 community.

Is there a way to enable it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that using **Local IIS** is ok. If it is not ok jump to the **View in browser** part. If you have doubts jump to **Alternative solution**.

**Step 1:**

Go to Project properties > Web > Servers.

- Choose Local IIS
- Give a name to Project URL (ex: `http://project.dev`)

**Step 2:**

Open Internet Information Services (IIS) Manager > Sites > Right click > Add Web Site.

- Site name "project"
- Physical path "path to your project"
- Host, same as defined on project "project.dev"

**Note:**
If you let this set create  an app pool for you check if it is using the right framework

Application Pools > Right click on the app pool > Basic settings > Choose framework.

**Step 3:**

Go to folder "C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc" > Eight click on file hosts > Edit as administrator.

- Add line `127.0.0.1 project.dev #same name as project url and host`

Now you can work on your HTML/Css/js just only by saving the files and if changed code behind just build the project. (Sometimes a reload of the page instead of just a refresh is needed to clear some cache).

**Last Step**:

Hit project.dev on your browser.

Ps. assuming that you use other name than project.dev hit that URL instead.

**View in browser**

If you just want **IIS Express**.
Richt click on project > View > View in Browser (this should keep it running)

- shortcut Ctrl+Shift+W [**source**](http://visualstudioshortcuts.com/2015/)
- **EDIT** In some cases the shortcut could not be available so go to tools > options > environment> keyboard and search for `viewinbrowser` and see if you have the shortcut right for the command

**Alternative solution**

If **none** of the **above works** for you, you can try to uncheck "Enable Edit and Continue"

**For All projects**

Tools > Options > Debugging (tip: scroll down) > Edit and Continue

- uncheck Enable Edit and Continue check box. [**source**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7yty6a48.aspx)

**Just for project of choice**

Project properties > Web > (tip: scroll down)

- uncheck "Enable Edit and Continue"

Comment: The solution to right click on project -> View in Browser does work, but is there a way to make this default?  The keyboard shortcut does not work (which is super odd as Visual Studio shows the same short cut as in your post).

Comment: @MyDaftQuestions Probably the schema of keyboard is messed up, can you go to tools > options > environment> keyboard and search for viewinbrowser and see if you have the shortcut right for the command.